# Problems with remote debugging with kernel mode driver

Tags: kernel, driver, wdk, wdm, wdf

I use windows7 host machine there I installed Vusual Studio 2013 and WDK 8.1
Also I have Windows 10 virtual machine using Virtual Box.

I create new KMDF driver from template and try to debug it.

I succsesfully provisioned target machine (which is virtual with win10), driver successfully deployed, but debugger still inactive. This is log from Debugger Inmmediate Window:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
                  Starting New Debugger Session         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.3.9600.17336 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

SM72UC\User (npipe WinIDE_01D16A27752C70A4) connected at Thu Feb 18 11:36:27 2016

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.3.9600.17336 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Opened \\.\pipe\com1
Waiting to reconnect...
[11:36:28:242]: Removing any existing files from the remote driver folder
[11:36:28:771]: Removing any existing files from test execution folder

te.exe "%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestTasks.dll" /select:"@Name='DriverTestTasks::_DriverRemoval'" /p:"InfFile=KMDFTest.inf" /p:"Debug=1" /p:"ImportDriver=1" /p:"RemoveDriver=1" /p:"HardwareId=Root\KMDFTest" /p:"CertificateFile=KMDFTestPackage.cer" /p:"PackageGuid={A23BA0FC-7265-4E3C-B99F-1E7A04AD970D}" /rebootStateFile:%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Logs\DriverTestReboot.xml /enableWttLogging /wttDeviceString:$LogFile:file="%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Logs\Driver_Removal_(x64)_(possible_reboot)_00009.wtl",writemode=append,encoding=unicode,nofscache=true,EnableLvl="WexStartTest|WexEndTest|WexXml|WexProperty|WexCreateContext|WexCloseContext|*" /runas:Elevated
[11:36:52:104]: Result Summary: Total=1, Passed=1, Failed=0, Blocked=0, Warned=0, Skipped=0
[11:36:52:705]: Removing any existing files from test execution folder

te.exe "%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestTasks.dll" /select:"@Name='DriverTestTasks::_DriverPreparation'" /p:"InfFile=KMDFTest.inf" /p:"Debug=1" /p:"ImportDriver=1" /p:"RemoveDriver=1" /p:"HardwareId=Root\KMDFTest" /p:"CertificateFile=KMDFTestPackage.cer" /p:"PackageGuid={A23BA0FC-7265-4E3C-B99F-1E7A04AD970D}" /rebootStateFile:%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Logs\DriverTestReboot.xml /enableWttLogging /wttDeviceString:$LogFile:file="%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Logs\Driver_Preparation_(x64)_(possible_reboot)_00009.wtl",writemode=append,encoding=unicode,nofscache=true,EnableLvl="WexStartTest|WexEndTest|WexXml|WexProperty|WexCreateContext|WexCloseContext|*" /runas:Elevated
[11:36:58:137]: Result Summary: Total=1, Passed=1, Failed=0, Blocked=0, Warned=0, Skipped=0
[11:36:58:792]: Removing any existing files from test execution folder

te.exe "%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestTasks.dll" /select:"@Name='DriverTestTasks::_RunProcess'" /p:"BinaryPath=%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\devcon.exe" /p:"Arguments=-f install %SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Drivers\KMDFTest.inf Root\KMDFTest" /p:"ExitCodes=0" /p:"WorkingFolder=%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Drivers" /p:"LogOutput=1" /rebootStateFile:%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Logs\DriverTestReboot.xml /enableWttLogging /wttDeviceString:$LogFile:file="%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Logs\Driver_Install_(x64)_(possible_reboot)_00003.wtl",writemode=append,encoding=unicode,nofscache=true,EnableLvl="WexStartTest|WexEndTest|WexXml|WexProperty|WexCreateContext|WexCloseContext|*" /runas:Elevated
[11:37:22:743]: Result Summary: Total=1, Passed=1, Failed=0, Blocked=0, Warned=0, Skipped=0
[11:37:23:235]: Removing any existing files from test execution folder

te.exe "%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestTasks.dll" /select:"@Name='DriverTestTasks::_DriverPostInstall'" /rebootStateFile:%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Logs\DriverTestReboot.xml /enableWttLogging /wttDeviceString:$LogFile:file="%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Logs\Driver_Post_Install_Actions_(x64)_(possible_reboot)_00009.wtl",writemode=append,encoding=unicode,nofscache=true,EnableLvl="WexStartTest|WexEndTest|WexXml|WexProperty|WexCreateContext|WexCloseContext|*" /runas:Elevated
[11:37:25:227]: Result Summary: Total=1, Passed=1, Failed=0, Blocked=0, Warned=0, Skipped=0
[11:37:25:775]: Driver Installation summary:
[11:37:25:781]:   Driver Removal (x64) (possible reboot): Pass
[11:37:25:784]:   Driver Preparation (x64) (possible reboot): Pass
[11:37:25:785]:   Driver Install (x64) (possible reboot): Pass
[11:37:25:787]:   Driver Post Install Actions (x64) (possible reboot): Pass
```

after this debugger stucks, console is inactive and show me text "Debuggee is running..." I don't reach my breakpoint at the DriverEntry function, don't see any debug messages from kernel and driver.

I also tried netwok settings for debug, but same result.

What wrong?

Is there a VirtualBox problem? Or this is because I try to debug win7 driver on win10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waiting to reconnect... means debugger wait for target machine answer to it. While target machine running nothing happend. You need to break it. In WinDBG by pressing Ctrl+C, in Visual Studio by pressing Break icon.